# Using SpringFox to document my Spring RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I'm trying to use SpringFox to document a @RestController in my application but so far I've been met with stout resistance.
I've been following this [example](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) but whenever I start I get the following exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'

I know that's not much to go on so I managed to reproduce it on a pretty simple standalone application:

```
package example.swagger;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(AppConfig.class);
        builder.child(SwaggerConfiguration.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

The configuration classes used are as follows:

```
package example.swagger;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AppConfig {
}
```

And finally:

```
package example.swagger;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
}
```

I've been struggling with this for days. Any help would be most appreciated! ;)

Comment: I think you get this exception too: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and there you get to know what is missing.

Comment: I know that the underlying exception really is NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping].
But is the RequestMappingInfoHandler a bean I should define explicitly? Why isn't it working out-of-the-box like it should?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to take a guess, it's probably because you are not running with the latest version of springfox. Could you try upgrading to ***2.5.0***. It may fix your problem.

PS: Don't have the link to the issue that fixes this handy, but I'll update this answer when I do.

Comment: I was using 2.4.0 but upgrading to 2.5.0 didn't help